# why bazel not search system include paths

Tags: c++, bazel

The error is

```
.../demo.cc:5:10: fatal error: 'city.h' file not found
#include <city.h>
```

`cityhash` is installed by `brew install cityhash`.

`city.h` can be found in `/usr/local/include`.

And, it is actually in the search path of `clang`.

```
$ clang -E -xc++ - -v

Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.14.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -E -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name - -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=10.14 -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 450.3 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/local/include -stdlib=libc++ -Wno-atomic-implicit-seq-cst -Wno-framework-include-private-from-public -Wno-atimport-in-framework-header -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/formath/git/mlp -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 202 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.14.0 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o - -x c++ -
clang -cc1 version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3) default target x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

My `Bazel` version is `1.1.0`.

I have saw a same question which is not fixed right now.

```
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5391
```

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround you could add a `cc_library` for a `new_local_repository` that wraps a view on `/usr/local`.

In your `WORKSPACE` file define a `new_local_repository` with the `path` attribute set to `/usr/local` and the `build_file` pointing to a `BUILD` file local to the workspace, for example:

```py
# WORKSPACE
new_local_repository(
  name = "usr_local",
  path = "/usr/local",
  build_file = "third_party/usr_local.BUILD",
)
```

The `third_party/usr_local.BUILD` file could have different rules for different libraries you want to wrap. For `cityhash` you could do something like this (I don't know the structure of the `cityhash` library, so I'm guessing here about the `.so`):

```py
# third_party/usr_local.BUILD
cc_library(
  name = "cityhash",
  hdrs = glob(["include/cityhash/**"]),
  srcs = [
    "lib64/cityhash.so",
  ],
  includes = [
    "include/cityhash",
  ],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Notice that the paths will be relative to the *new local repository* location (so in this case `/usr/local`).

Finally in your `BUILD` file you can reference the `cityhash` targetu using:

```py
# BUILD
cc_binary(
  name = "main",
  srcs = [
    "main.cc",
  ],
  deps = [
    "@usr_local//:cityhash",
  ],
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This method works. However, I really want to know why bazel could not search system include paths.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood. I think that the default include path comes from the Bazel c++ toolchain configuration - you could check `cc_toolchain_config.bzl` on the bazel repo.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work when the library you are referring to itself are using #include <> instead of #include "". The only way to make it work seems to be making clang make the library is a system library.

Comment: @formath This should be the design choice of bazel. Google really loves monorepo.

Comment: I get `no such package '@usr_local//': In new_local_repository rule //external:usr_local the 'build_file' attribute does not specify an existing file (myrepo/third_party/usr_local.BUILD does not exist)`, but the file exists there and I can open it.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. How do you then include stuff in the .cc file? I am trying this with SFML and I get a 'file not found' for #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>.